# Como usar o mesmo id mais de uma vez com o getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, pessoal. Tudo bem?

Tenho um cronômetro que está em javascript e quero que ele apareça mais de uma vez em uma página específica.

O problema é que ele funciona apenas na primeira vez em que aparece na página.

Eu imagino que seja por causa dos ids que são duplicados na página em html (id="days" id="hours" id="minutes" id="seconds") quando tento duplicar o segundo cronômetro. Mas se quero chamar os cronômetros preciso usar esses ids.

Para tentar contornar o problema tentei usar o getElementsByClassName() no lugar do getElementById(). Assim, poderia usar classes em vez de ids no meu HTML. Logo, poderia chamar o código javascript através da classe mais de uma vez, sem problemas. Porém, meu código não funcionou com o getElementsByClassName(). O cronômetro simplesmente não aparece quando tento usar essa função.

Alguém tem alguma solução para que esse cronômetro funcione mais de uma vez na mesma página?

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + ' ' + dd + ', ' + yyyy;
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date(today).getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = countDown - now;

      document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
      
    }, second)
```

```html
<div class="conteiner-countdown-loop">
  <ul>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="days"></span>dias</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="hours"></span>Horas</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="minutes"></span>Minutos</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="seconds"></span>Segundos</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá, Bacco. Tudo bem?
Por alguma motivo, este código deixou de funcionar de ontem para hoje. Eu tentei entender o problema mas não consegui. Suponho que seja na função que obtém a data de hoje. Poderia me dar uma luz? Desde já agradeço a sua atenção.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Soluções tem muitas, mas com o JS que está usando, o ID é necessário
(mas tem uma alternativa com `class` no final).

Você pode numerar os IDs:

```
<li class="countdown-loop"><span id="days1"></span> Dias</li>
...
<li class="countdown-loop"><span id="days2"></span> Dias</li>
...
<li class="countdown-loop"><span id="days3"></span> Dias</li>
...
```

E na hora de atualizar, usar um loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
  document.getElementById('days' + i).innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
  //                             ^-- note a concatenação
  ...
```

Provavelmente você vai usar tempos diferentes em cada cronômetro, aí é só você mudar a referência de tempo em cada iteração do loop, seja com um array ou outra técnica qualquer, mas isso foge do problema da pergunta, que foi solucionado com o loop. Programar, no fim das contas, é isso, descobrir como usar os recursos da linguagem para resolver a tarefa.

### Demonstração:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + ' ' + dd + ', ' + yyyy;
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date(today).getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = countDown - now;

      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
        document.getElementById('days'+i).innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById('hours'+i).innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById('minutes'+i).innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById('seconds'+i).innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
      }
    }, second)
```

```html
<div class="conteiner-countdown-loop">
  <ul>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="days1"></span> Dias</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="hours1"></span> Horas</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="minutes1"></span> Minutos</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="seconds1"></span> Segundos</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="days2"></span> Dias</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="hours2"></span> Horas</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="minutes2"></span> Minutos</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="seconds2"></span> Segundos</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="days3"></span> Dias</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="hours3"></span> Horas</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="minutes3"></span> Minutos</li>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span id="seconds3"></span> Segundos</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Se os cronômetros forem iguais, pode usar `class`:

Note que o `getElementsByClassName` retorna vários elementos, você precisa iterar sobre eles.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + ' ' + dd + ', ' + yyyy;
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date(today).getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {
      let now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = countDown - now,
          spanSeconds = document.getElementsByClassName('seconds'),
          i = spanSeconds.length,
          valueSeconds = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
  
      while(i--) spanSeconds[i].innerText = valueSeconds;
    }, second)
```

```html
<div class="conteiner-countdown-loop">
  <ul>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span class="seconds"></span> Segundos</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span class="seconds"></span> Segundos</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="countdown-loop"><span class="seconds"></span> Segundos</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Bacco. Eu nunca pensei em colocar um contador para incrementar aos ids no código javascript. Deu muito certo, porém resolve parte do problema porque os ids do código HTML não são variáveis.

Na verdade eu não usaria tempos diferentes. Os cronômetros são iguais. Apenas se repetem na página.

Comment: Mas pensei aqui que posso criar uma função em php que incremente um valor i ao id do HTML. Como você fez no javascript. Só não sei como o valor i do html vai ser exatamente igual ao valor i do javascript. Será que este seria um bom caminho. Se sim, vou pensar como fazer isso. Assim que tiver pronto eu posto aqui.

Comment: Basta gerar o JS com o mesmo PHP que gera o HTML - sugiro não postar junto, pois vc fez uma pergunta de um problema de JS, o PHP é mera implementação e só vai acrescentar ruido (outros visitantes podem chegar a esta mesma pergunta sem necessariamente ser um projeto em PHP).

Comment: Acrescentei um exemplo com classe, ja que sao iguais

Comment: O exemplo com classe funcionou perfeitamente. Eu estava utilizando a função com classe de forma muito errada. Agradeço muitíssimo a sua atenção, Bacco. Tenha uma ótima semana!